# Load image from URL in different thread asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-core, url

I would like to ask for help for one problem which after some time of researching, is still unclear how to be solved.
I have simple asp.net core web app to store customers and the task is to load images of the customer(profile picture) from url using another thread.
The url is stored along with other customer info: name, phone in a db in 1 table.
My current implementation is that I have a view (called "Details") where the image is loaded from the url:

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Url)" alt="Picture has not been provided" width="300" />
```

How can implement the code so that loading of the picture from url is with another thread.
I am not very advanced so can you please try explain a it if you come with some suggestions.

1. So far I have read that there are some options: tasks, thread, ajax but the requirement is clear: "use another thread to load the image" so I am a bit unsure if I use for example task(await), will this actually comply strictly with the requirement.
2. If I need to create a new thread, does that means, I need to create a new method in the CustomersController in my Details method and then somehow return again the image to the view?

Index View where all customers are listed:
[image]

Details View where the picture for customer is displayed:
[image]

Comment: Its a bit unclear on what do you mean by load the image on a different thread? Do you load the user profile picture from the DB before calling the view?

Comment: Yes , this is what I do. I have 4 fields in db>

Comment: Ok, can you explain to me the different thread part? What do you want to achieve by  using a different thread? Download the image from somewhere and save it as a file, or just show it in the browser?

Comment: Sorry , my comment was uncomplete:
load = display
Yes ,I have url in database. I have 4 fields in db:
id, name, phone, url(string)
in the web project I have:
CustomerController (Crud opperations + Details method which I use to display the profile picture )
I have also Customer Model with the same 4 fields from above.
and Views(index, create, delete, update, details)
So my logic is that when a user clicks on details for a customer record in the web app, then there is shown all the customer details and the picture is displayed from the url associated with the customer. Is that clear en.?

Comment: The requirement is not designed by me and I have only this as stated in description. In my understanding, the meaning is that there has to be used a new thread to remove the load from displaying the image. I am not sure actually now, is there any download process for the picture in the img html tag?

Comment: Let me know if it is still unclear, so I will try to explain more and eventually post picture of the details page in UI

Comment: And when the details are clicked, the html for the details is fetched from the server?

Comment: Yes. I will add screenshots as its gonna be easier. The code will come as well in a minute

Comment: Also, please avoid code screenshots and and post all the relevant code, controller, view, model, javascript etc. so the question will be much clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215255/discussion-between-borka-and-georgi).